# Simulate user click in chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

Why can't I trigger or simulate user click using chrome's console in browser? like I have a link on a page I do `$('#app .mylink').click()` it should go somewhere.

Comment: You can. Is your selector correct and do they have jQuery? If not, use vanilla JS

Comment: Chrome's inspector has a jQuery-like helper (`$`), but that's it. You'd need to implement it yourself when interacting within the page as @Li357 said.

Comment: @Phix what do you mean by implement myself? isn't `$('#app .mylink').click()` is firing click already on an element?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$` in Chrome's console [is an alias for `document.querySelector()`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#queryselector), except when it's not. If `$` is declared in the page, usually by jQuery, `$` in the console will point to that instead.

Calling `click` on a jQuery object representing an `a` element won't perform the native navigation, but calling [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) on the native [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) will. If you know the page you're working with uses jQuery, you'll need to retrieve the native `HTMLElement` from the jQuery object:

```
$('#app .mylink')[0].click(); // assuming you want to click the first element returned
```

But if jQuery's not involved, that won't work. Best to be unambiguous:

```
document.querySelector('#app .mylink').click();
```

Comment: should be a way to do this in the UI